# cmdline Unix Permissions bits calculator

Tags: permissions, umask

I'd like to convert the Unix Permissions bits from octal to symbolic mode and viceversa.
eg.:

```
$ mode-encode 'ugo+rwx'
0000

$ mode-decode 0000
ugo+rwx
```

I know there are [online permission bits calculators](http://permissions-calculator.org/) and `chmod` supports passing the bits in both ways, but i'd like a bash code snippet i can use with commands that does not support the symbolic mode.

EDIT: i'd like to get the permission bits, not the umask!

Comment: Note that for some values of the symbolic forms, the result will depend on the current umask. like for `umask +r`, or `umask g=u` (that one not supported by all implementation even though it's POSIX)

Comment: `ugo+rwx` gives 0000 by the way, not 0777

Comment: Your latest edit makes it a bit confusing. Isn't @schily's answer what you want? If you want the complement, you can always do `printf '%o\n' "$((value ^ 511))"`

Comment: indeed i've noticed the results are inverted from [what i expected](http://permissions-calculator.org/) (the previous examples were actually correct), so i had to add complement step to the @schily's answer

Comment: It's still unclear, all the `a+x`, `go=u` symbolic notations are _relative_, what do you want them to be relative to? Your question is now completely different from the original one which invalidates all the current answers. I'd suggest you revert this one to the original and post a separate  question for your new requirements.

Comment: I'd like the converter to not depend on any local setting, so i can use it on remote systems as well (e.g via ftp). So i guess i should assume the default umask is 0000?

Answer (score 3):

In any POSIX shell, you can call:

```
savmask=$(umask)
umask someval
umask -S  # outputs the symbolic form
umask     # outputs the octal form
umask -- "$savmask"
```

You could put this into a function

```
printmask() {
   savmask=$(umask) || return
   umask -- "$1" || return
   umask -S
   umask
   umask -- "$savmask"
}
```

Or use a subshell to avoid having to save and restore the umask:

```
printmask() (
  umask -- "${1?Please specify a umask}" || exit
  umask -S
  umask
)
```

Comment: ok, i've added `umask 0777` at the beginning of the last `printmask` function to always have the full mask.