# How do I return octal from Bash's arithmetic expansion?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic, shell-builtin, bash-expansion

As clearly spelled out in the Bash documentation on [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic), if you prefix a number with a `0` within an arithmetic expansion expression (*e.g.*, `$(( expr ))`), it's treated as octal. Similarly, you can use `b#n` for a number `n` in  base `b`.

However, irrespective of the base you use for the arithmetic *inside* the expression, the value is always returned as base 10. How do I *return* octal from the result of an arithmetic expansion?

*My original use case for this was to warn a user that the permissions on their `~/.my.cnf` were too lax (group- or world-readable) by ANDing together the permission bits of the file with a bitmask, but I later decided that testing the output of `find ~/.my.cnf -perm +0044` is probably cleaner, and more portable, since `stat` format strings are not standard between macOS/BSD and Linux. Yet, the question remains.*

Comment: why do you want to return an octal representation of a number from an arithmetic operation?

Comment: As stated, to be able to view and manipulate file permissions in numeric (octal) rather than symbolic mode. This was sort of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but no one else on SE seemed to have asked "X," and the solution I found for "X" was still interesting and useful to me, so I recorded it here for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidbit that I happened upon in a comment in [another SE thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465483/278323): you can just use `printf` with the `%o` (octal) format string.

A working example:

```bsh
# figure out stat(1) flags based on OS
if [[ $(uname -s) == Linux ]]; then PERMS='-c %a' else PERMS='-f %Lp'; fi

stat $PERMS ~/.my.cnf
# result: 600 (not group/world readable)

# permission bits if group/world readable
bitmask=044
perm=$(stat $PERMS ~/.my.cnf)
printf "%o\n" $(( 0$perm & 0$bitmask ))
# result: 0

# now make the file group-readable and try again
chmod 640 ~/.my.cnf
perm=$(stat $PERMS ~/.my.cnf)
printf "%o\n" $(( 0$perm & 0$bitmask ))
# result: 40
```

### Bonus: other solutions

If I don't want to *see* the permissions bits in octal, I could achieve my original aim without using `printf` at all. If all I care about is whether *any* of the bits in the `bitmask` were set, just testing if the result is non-zero is sufficient:

```bsh
if (( 0$perm & 0$bitmask )); then
    echo "Permissions $perm are too lax." >&2
fi
```

If you wanted to know whether *all* the bits in `bitmask` were set, then compare the result of ANDing them together to the bitmask, something like this:

```bsh
(( (0777 & 0066) == 0066 )) && echo "Oh noes, group AND world writable! "
```